# Add dollar sign and commas to a number?

Tags: formatting

I have a field on the admin side where a user enters a number for a price. If a user enters 1000000 I'd like to be able to display on the front-end $1,000,000.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

**Edit**
More details, the post is a custom post type 'property'.

To add the meta fields on the back-end I'm using Meta Box Script, http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2011/03/meta-box-script-update-v30.html

The code to display the numbers on the front-end I use

```
$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_propPrice', true); echo $meta;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To format number, you can use the function `number_format_i18n` (it's not documented now, but you can see its source [here](http://phpxref.com/xref/wordpress/_functions/number_format_i18n.html)). Its work is format the number based on the language. You might want to look at `number_format` ([PHP built_in function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), and is used by `number_format_i18n`) to have more control to decimal point and thousand separator.

In your case, this code will help you:

```
$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_propPrice', true);
echo '$' . number_format($meta, 0, '.', ',');
```

Comment: thanks, for the answer, for your blog, the Meta Box Script... everything, it's been a huge help with my first wordpress project

Answer (score 0):

Just a **guess** (you really need to be more specific in your Q - what screen, how did you add it, metabox/settings section/bla???)...

```
$foo = get_option( 'your_option_name' ); 
echo '$'.$foo['bar']; // where bar is the searched value in the options array
```

Comment: I have added more details, I figure I can add the dollar sign in between echo and $meta; but still not sure how to add comma's. Thanks.